# Can't find the element in selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i would like to scrape the following webpage: [Mercator Shop](https://trgovina.mercator.si/market/brskaj), but i don't know how i can close the window in the picture bellow "Izbira načina prevzema artiklov":

[image: Mercator Shop frame]

I already tried with copy-ing the XPATH of x button (//*[@id="237955"]/div/div/div[1](https://trgovina.mercator.si/market/brskaj)/a), but it throws the error and saying that there is no such element.

Here is my code, which doesn't work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://trgovina.mercator.si/market/brskaj")
time.sleep(5)

x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div")
x.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/a[1]").click()

y = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[9]")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/a[2]").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gdpr-cookie-accept"]').click()

g = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="237955"]/div/div/div[1]/a')
```

Error Message: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="237955"]/div/div/div[1](https://trgovina.mercator.si/market/brskaj)/a"}

Any help is welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using their API:

```py
import requests

url = "https://trgovina.mercator.si/market/products/browseProducts/getProducts"
params = {"limit": 100, "offset": 0}
data = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

---

Sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using explicit wait as below
WebDriverWait wait =New WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(20));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(“enter xpath here”))).click();

OR
it can be a iframe that needs handling as below
List frame=driver.findElements(By.tagName(“iframe”));
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
Then find required element.
After that
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Use a for loop if in case of multiple frames.You can find no of frames by using frame.size() function.

Answer (score 0):

It will make it easier to find the button with inspect and get the full path. To reach the correct result, you should use the browser that webdriver opens.

If you replace the last part of your code with the Xpath below, it will work.

```
g = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal-dialog modal-lg']/div[@class='modal-content']/div[@class='modal-header']/a")
    
g.click()
```